# Getting current time of Denmark

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-emulator, location

I am using following method for getting current time in HH:MM format.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    try {
        OpenTime = dateFormat.parse(open_t);
        ClosedTime = dateFormat.parse(closed_t);
        CurrentTime = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here the code is working fine (that means in India/Delhi). But I think my code is not working in Denmark, as its impossible to go there to check the functionality. So I need some advancement in my code so that either it will work on current timing of Denmark or It should work on Current timing of place where the Android Device is located.

Comment: Why would you think it doesn't work in Denmark?

Comment: on the basis of Client Comments which is situated there

Comment: I think it actually pics the time and date settings of the device. Can you change the locale of the device to Denmark settings and see if the code is working?

Comment: You need to include all relevant info. Now you've told us why you think this, but we still don't know in what way it doesn't work, what your expected output is compared to the actual one, etc.

Comment: You'd be much better off using Joda Time, to be honest - where there's a specific `LocalTime` type, as it sounds like that's what you're trying to model.

Answer (score 1):

well it depnends what the locale is set for device on which your code is deployed.For specifically getting denmark time irrespective of locale try below

```
Calendar cal1 =Calendar(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale) ;
SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(date_format.format(cal1.getTime()));

for info on denmark timezone/locale here is the link
http://www.localeplanet.com/java/da-DK/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.TimeZone tz = java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1");
java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tz);

System.out.println(c.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
```